# Jolt spec convert 2d array to 1d array

Tags: jolt

How to convert 2d array to 1d array

```json
{ "test": [ ["1", "2", "3"], ["4"] ] }
```

to

```json
{ "test" : ["1", "2", "3", "4"] }
```

I tried multiple things and it didn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This spec should do the trick:

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "test": {
        "*": {
          "*": "test"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```